# App not letting device to go into sleep mode

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I'm developing an application in which I'm using an `activity` which will come on top of default lock screen of the device. All things are perfectly fine, but I'm having issues with `display timeout of the screen`. Every time when my `activity` comes, the device does not go into sleep mode. Why?

Here is my code snippet for `Service` class and `BroadcastReceiver` class. I could find out what is hindering the device screen timeout mode.

**BroadcastReceiver class**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

        wasScreenOn = false;
        Intent intent11 = new Intent(context, LockActivity.class);
        intent11.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        context.startActivity(intent11);

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

        wasScreenOn = true;
        Intent intent11 = new Intent(context, LockActivity.class);
        intent11.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

        Intent intent11 = new Intent(context, LockActivity.class);

        intent11.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent11);

    }

}
```

**Service Class**

```
public class PerkLockService extends Service {

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock k1;

    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    k1 = km.newKeyguardLock("IN");
    k1.disableKeyguard();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

    mReceiver = new PerkLockReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    System.out.println("Service Created");

    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    System.out.println("Service Destroyed");

    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    stopSelf();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Here is what I'm using `permissions` in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

**Update:**

Adding my `MainAcitivty.java` from where I'm calling my service and `StateListener()` method:

`MainActivity.java`

```
try {
        // initialize receiver

        startService(new Intent(this, PerkLockService.class));

        StateListener phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

/**
 * Listen to the state of the phone, like ringing and alarm, and it
 * automatically dismiss the activity and show up the proper screen
 */
class StateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            finish();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            System.out.println("call Activity off hook");
            finish();

            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

I could not find what is keeping the device to go to sleep with my app.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you acquiring a wakelock in the LockActivity ?

Comment: No, I'm not using it anywhere.

Comment: what is the display timeout set to? Is it possible that it is just set rather large and you aren't waiting long enough?

Comment: My device default screen timeout is 15 seconds. It is working fine when I try this in a separate project. But this is not working for this particular project.

Comment: put a log in your screen off intent receiver to see if it ever fires.. Maybe it is trying to turn the screen off, but that receiver is re-launching the activity which could be turning the screen back on. It might happen so fast that it would appear to never turn off.

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` is always called, whenever I press power button to turn off display, but by default it is not letting it. Doing you find any flaw or something in my code, or any other way of doing it so that this issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue here by adding `Clear All Flags` for keeping screen on.
Here is the code which I have used:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```