# Looking for tools and methods to use to narrow down causes for a React Native app to stop a device from going into sleep mode

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, debugging

I am maintaining an App that has been created in React Native targeted at Android tablet devices. The issue that I am currently experiencing is that when the app is active but has not had any activity, the device will not go into sleep mode after the assigned period of inactivity whilst the is app active.

I have been attempting to find any processes that could be preventing the app from allowing the device to go into sleep mode and have not been able to find anything through Chromes debugging tools or Reactotron.

I did find this question [App not letting device to go into sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383777/app-not-letting-device-to-go-into-sleep-mode) so my next step is to look at our third party packages as well as our own Java files, though our customisation of them have been very minimal and to the best of my knowledge there has not been any code added intentionally to stop a device from going into sleep mode.

What I am looking for is any additional tools as well as any methods that I could use to narrow down my search for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Was this application created using Expo?

If so you can prevent the screen from sleeping by using `KeepAwake` as documented here in the Expo documentation https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/keep-awake/

There is also information inThe github repo which details how to use this in applications that aren't using Expo too : https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-keep-awake

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. We're not using Expo within our app and have not added any code with the intent of preventing the device from going to sleep.

Comment: Apologies, I misread our question, I thought you were attempting to achieve such functionality.

I guess to debug it you could narrow it down by temporarily creating a component for testing each of the packages that you use on app entry, so that you can try to eliminate each package.

This is pretty strange and unintended behaviour, I would imagine this is going to be a pain to get to the bottom of, I don't envy you. Good Luck!